# MySQL selection jumps from 300 ms to 20 seconds for 5 rows extra

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, selection

I have a blob in my database table. If I select 10 rows of the table (each row containing 1 blob), it takes 300 milliseconds.
However, if I select 15 rows, it takes 20 seconds. I don't understand what is going on. The file that is selected is an image of 1 MB.

```
public void find() throws SQLException, IOException {
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\test\\test.jpg"));
        InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("photo");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
}
```

I honestly don't know why such small difference takes up so much time.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

***Edit for extra notes:***

- Yes, the overwriting of the same image is intentional. (sorry for not pointing that out)
- Using rs.getBlob("photo").getBinaryStream() has still the same effect.
- The execution time of the method find() is being benchmarked via JMH. The piece of code above remains the same.
- The exact same code and SQL is running for a 'contact' table that for the first test has 100 rows (of which 10 are selected) and the other 150 rows (of which 15 are selected).
- The blob is inside the contact table.

The SQL:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM contact c INNER JOIN contact_address ca  ON c.id=ca.contact_id INNER JOIN groups_contact gc ON gc.contact_id=c.id INNER JOIN groups gr WHERE ca.country=? AND gr.name=? GROUP by c.id";
stm = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stm.setString(1, "NL");
stm.setString(2, "Friends");
stm.addBatch();
```

Update:

(measuring method is modified please see the above)

```
 Selecting 10 rows: 239 ms.
 Selecting 15 rows: 26378 ms.
 Selecting 25 rows: 34888 ms.
 Selecting 50 rows: 73267 ms.
 Selecting 75 rows: 81885 ms.
 Selecting 100 rows: 106528 ms.
```

Creations of table:

```
String createUserTable = "CREATE TABLE User (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))";
String createGroupTable = "CREATE TABLE Groups (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , name VARCHAR(255), user_id INTEGER not NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id))";
String createContactTable = "CREATE TABLE Contact (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , firstname VARCHAR(255), lastname VARCHAR(255), note VARCHAR(255), photo MEDIUMBLOB, user_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id))";
String createGroupContactTable = "CREATE TABLE Groups_Contact (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, contact_id INTEGER not NULL, group_id INTEGER not NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES Contact(id), FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES Groups(id))";
String createContactAddressTable = "CREATE TABLE Contact_Address (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , street VARCHAR(255), number INTEGER, zipcode VARCHAR(255), city VARCHAR(255), country VARCHAR(255), addresstype VARCHAR(255), contact_id INTEGER not null, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES Contact(id))";
String createContactPhoneTable = "CREATE TABLE Contact_Phone (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , type VARCHAR(255), number VARCHAR(255), contact_id INTEGER not null, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES Contact(id))";
String createContactEmailTable = "CREATE TABLE Contact_Email (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , type VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), contact_id INTEGER not null, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES Contact(id))";
```

Comment: Could you try using rs.getBlob("photo").getBinaryStream()? Also, you're overwriting each image into the same file, is that intentional?

Comment: are you really saying the execution of the sql statement has that difference, or that the program as written down above has that difference?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I really appreciate it. I updated my post with answers to all your questions. Hmmh, maybe I should put the blob on a separate table. I really don't understand why 5 rows make that big of a difference...

Comment: Two things - 1) You don't have a correlation between `groups` and anything else (I'd expect something to `group_contact`), so you're getting a partial Cartesian product (too many rows), **and** probably unrelated rows and 2) You seem to be trying to get a single row (given the `GROUP BY`, but you're going to end up with non-deterministic values from anything giving multiple rows.  Where are the duplicates actually coming from?  It's best to limit that earlier.

Comment: If you comment out all lines for writing the file, but not for reading the blob, is there still such great difference?

Comment: @Kwebble, good point. If I comment out the writing of the file, the results are still the same except the jump is from 100 ms to +-15 seconds instead 300 ms to 20 seconds. (I don't remember the exact time (laptop is out of battery sorry!), they are a little less but still a big gap exists between them)

@ Clockwork-Muse I believe the duplicates are coming from the user table. But I have 1 user in that table who has e.g. 100 contacts. 1/10 contacts lives and works in another country. Every contact is placed in 2 groups (which are the same in all contacts).

Comment: Your copy loop is incorrect. It should be like `while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { out.write(buffer, 0, count); }` You should also use a larger buffer, say 8192.

Comment: @EJP Thank you! It appears that the gap between fetching 10 and 15 is smaller now:
Fetching 10 gives me: 200 ms. Fetching 15 gives me 10 seconds. Still a big gap, but at least it is not fetching for 20 seconds anymore.
Is there anything else that may work to narrow the gap?

Comment: Please show your table definitions including constraints. Can you get time taken as the performance as the size grows at multiple sizes? Please update your question appending the new code post-EJP.

Comment: @philipxy thank you for your comment philipxy. I updated my post along with the new code, creation of the table and measuring time.

Comment: Please run and report EXPLAIN for the 10 &15 cases. Also, what is your storage engine?

Comment: Thank you for your reply again @philipxy. I am using MyISAM (default) as the storage engine. 
I put EXPLAIN in front of my query and tried to print it using rs.toString(). But it prints the object I guess. Do you perhaps know how I can output this explain result?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its not the joins? Some joins can be very slow, especially multiple joins. Often we had to run separate queries because joins might slow a query down.

Also what kind of indexes do you have?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure it is caused by the joins. I'm definitely sure it is not caused by the writing of the image though. You may be right and it is caused by the joins. But I have a feeling this is caused by the blob since I did not have any blob in my table before this measuring test. Before adding the blob, everything appeared to be linear.
I do not have indexes in my tables. 
It just feels weird why only 5 rows difference can make such a huge difference in time.